# Structure of coalgebra on $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, coalgebras

Is it possible to give the structure of a $\mathbb{Z}$-coalgebra on $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$? If so, how would the comultiplication and counit be defined?

Answer (score 3):

There is no $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ (when $n>0$).

Comment: Hmm.. if the ring in question had torsion, say it contained $Z/nZ$ as a subring then is should be possible?

Comment: Or... what assumptions would we have to impose on R, to make $Z/nZ$ and R-comodule?

Comment: Z/nZ is not an R-algebra for most R. Please ask (elsewhere) what you *really* want to know, including the *complete* context.

Comment: hmm... for what R would it have a coalgebra structure for though? :/